# Can any one please tell me what is the meaning of this Second IIFE in calling parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function (library) {
    // Calls the second IIFE and locally passes in the global jQuery, window, and document objects
    library(window, document, window.jQuery);
}
// Locally scoped parameters 
(function (window, document, $) {

    // Library code goes here

}));
```

The above code I found in a tutorial in the following link. Thanks in advance.

http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/

Comment: What is your question exactly? The meaning of every IIFE foremost is to create scope.

Comment: I cant understand this block of code in the entire tutorial. "library" is a parameter(function)?, within the same calling function?

Comment: `library` is the parameter of the first function definition, and yes, it is a function. The whole expression simplified is `(function(lib) { lib(); }(func));`, where `func` is actually the function definition `function(window, ...) { ... }`. There is nothing special about the code, it might just not be formatted in a very readable way.

Comment: if library is a function, where it is defined?, is it the same function it was calling from? like a recursion?, i'm confused. I understood IIFE, but this block confuses me alot.

Comment: As I said, `function(window, ...) { ... }` is the function that is passed in as `library`.

Comment: what is the use of making this way? For sending more parameters?

Comment: Usually the first function contains more logic, it doesn't just call `library`. This is common pattern when you want to make a library available in different environments, e.g. the browser, Node.js and as require.js module.

Comment: The article actually explains why the author is using this pattern: *"One of the con’s with using IIFE’s is readability. If you have a lot of JavaScript code inside of an IIFE, and you want to find the parameters that you are passing into an IIFE, then you need to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page. Luckily, there is a more readable pattern that I have begun to use [...] This IIFE pattern allows you see what global objects you are passing into your IIFE, without you having to scroll to the very bottom of a potentially very long file."*

Answer (score 3):

Lets have a look at how IIFE look like in the simplest case:

```
(function() {
   // ...
}());
```

The `()` after the closing curly brace are the the call operator. If we want to pass arguments to the IIFE, that is where we have to put them:

```
(function(value) {
    alert(value);
}(42));
```

This IIFE would `alert` the number 42.

Now, we can pass any value to a function, even functions themselves. Consider

```
function foo() {
   alert(42);
}

(function(callback) {
    callback();
}(foo));
```

Here we are passing the function `foo` as argument to the IIFE (`(foo)`) and call it (`callback()`).

But, instead of using a named function, we can just "inline" the function definition with the function call, just like we often to with callbacks. Thus, the above code is equivalent to

```
(function(callback) {
    callback();
}(function() {
   alert(42);
}));
```

I literally just replaced `foo` with `function() { alert(42); }`. And that is exactly the same structure you have in your example.

---

As for the purpose of this approach, the author actually explains it in the article:

> One of the con’s with using IIFE’s is readability. If you have a lot of JavaScript code inside of an IIFE, and you want to find the parameters that you are passing into an IIFE, then you need to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page. Luckily, there is a more readable pattern that I have begun to use
>
> [code example]
>
> This IIFE pattern allows you see what global objects you are passing into your IIFE, without you having to scroll to the very bottom of a potentially very long file."*

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood alot better.

Answer (score 0):

It's an IIFE within an IIFE. The outer IIFE is obvious.

```
(function (library) {
  // Calls the second IIFE and locally passes in the global jQuery, window, and document objects
  library(window, document, window.jQuery);
}(library))
```

What you refer to as the second IIFE is the definition of the library function, and it is passed as an argument to the first IIFE. It might be more obvious if it was written this way.

```
var library = (function (window, document, $) {
   // Library code goes here
});

(function (library) {
  // Calls the second IIFE and locally passes in the global jQuery, window, and document objects
  library(window, document, window.jQuery);
}(library))
```

Comment: *"It's an IIFE within an IIFE."* Actually, no, it's an IIFE that gets passed a function.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern allows one to see the arguments being passed into IIFE at the very top of the definition rather than having to scroll all the way down to the bottom.  That is all.

```
(function (a,b,c) {
    500 lines of code...
}(apple, banana, cantaloupe));
```

So instead of having to scroll down 500 lines to see what parameters a,b, and c are, use the suggested format to show the parameters at the top.

```
(function (xyz) {
  xyz(apple, banana, cantaloupe);
}(function (a,b,c) {
  500 lines of code...
}));
```